# Why is the output "cbe" rather than "bce" in this python program?

Tags: python

```
getDifference=lambda string1, string2: reduce((lambda character1, character2: character1+character2), (set(string1)-set(string2))) 

print getDifference('abcde','adf')
```

In the first line, I defined a lambda expression that finds the difference between string1 and string2. I assume the output should be "bce", but it is "cbe", why?

Comment: Wow. Write your code in a more confusing way.

Comment: sets are not ordered.

Comment: Am I wrong or could that whole function be written as `"".join(set(string1) - set(string2))`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker You are right, it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A set is an unordered collection of unique elements - so the order of the characters is not kept through the sets operation. Check here for more:

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

Comment: But why is it "cbe"? not "ebc", "ecb" or something else? What is the mechanism behind it?

Comment: Have a look at `set('abcde')`.  On my machine that was given out as `set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd'])`.  The internal order of the values depends on how they are hashed.  From your point of view this is not predictable, and you should not rely on any order you observe.  In the next version it might change.  If you need a certain order, you will have to `sort` it yourself after conversion to a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Python sets don't preserve ordering. To preserve the order, you can use a list comprehension:

```
def diff(s1, s2):
    return "".join([c for c in s1 if c not in s2])

diff('abcde','adf')     # 'bce'
```

Many set implementations use hashing, which mixed up the order of the elements as a side effect. Ordered set implementations such as treesets do exist, however.